# Can i Scale ValueAxis according to scale?

Tags: java, swing, graph, jfreechart

[image]

I'm using JFreeChart, I want to scale this graph according to scale given beside, How can i scale this graph? Is there any Solution to this problem?

While Googling, I found [writeScaledChartAsPNG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html#writeScaledChartAsPNG%28java.io.OutputStream,%20org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), can i use this, how?

Comment: You need to obtain the chart image as an instance of java.awt.Image class and then call getScaledInstance().

Comment: @trashgod: i've tried [this](http://pastebin.com/7rp1XSwg), but don't think, its useful because its scaling the image according to scale, I need to scale the rangeAxis, Can I scale it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to scale the `rangeAxis`

It looks like `writeScaledChartAsPNG()` simply resamples the existing chart. Instead, use a zoom-related method of [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html), such as `zoomInRange()`, and save the chart using `writeChartAsPNG()`. You might also experiment with `zoomRange()` on your `rangeAxis`.

Comment: yeah, really I found `zoomRange()` useful, but still I'm not understanding how its taking the parameter `(lowerPercent, upperPercent)`. How should i set this to zoom according to my scale? Currently I've done [this](http://pastebin.com/WWVFpMyf)

Comment: Interesting, I'd not used the feature before; [`zoomRange()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#line.1597) appears to want values between 0 and 1; try `rangeAxis.zoomRange(0.15, 0.50)`, for example.

Comment: it's ok... BTW, Thanks for helping throughout... :)))